# CodeIgniter Pagination - first page’s link doesn’t work, why?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I use pagination library on my site, my config is here:

```
$data['url_keyword'] = url_title($keyword, '_');
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'image/'.$data['url_keyword'].'/';
$config['per_page'] = 1;
$config['uri_segment']=3;
```

my urls are: `mysite/image/keyword/1` (page2), `mysite/image/keyword/2` (page3), `mysite/image/keyword/3` (page4), `mysite/image/keyword/4` (page5)

When I’m on page 2 (`mysite/image/keyword/1`) and click previous - it gets me into `mysite/image/keyword/` - which doesnt work, but `mysite/image/keyword/0` WORKS. Library just doesn’t add zero at the end of url.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!$this->uri->segment(3))
       $page = 0;

//Your other logic
```

By default if `$this->uri->segment(x)` is empty it will return false.
Without seeing your controller or view I can't be more specific on where to place this or what you are naming your variable. This should work in the instances in which you call: yoursite.com/image/keyword